# How to unfold a recursive function just once in Coq

Tags: recursion, coq, unfold

Here is a recursive function `all_zero` that checks whether all members of a list of natural numbers are zero:

```
Require Import Lists.List.
Require Import Basics.

Fixpoint all_zero ( l : list nat ) : bool :=
  match l with
  | nil => true
  | n :: l' => andb ( beq_nat n 0 ) ( all_zero l' )
  end.
```

Now, suppose I had the following goal

```
true = all_zero (n :: l')
```

And I wanted to use the `unfold` tactic to transform it to

```
true = andb ( beq_nat n 0 ) ( all_zero l' )
```

Unfortunately, I can't do it with a simple `unfold all_zero` because the tactic will eagerly find and replace all instances of `all_zero`, including the one in the once-unfolded form, and it turns into a mess. Is there a way to avoid this and unfold a recursive function just once?

I know I can achieve the same results by proving an ad hoc equivalence with `assert (...) as X`, but it is inefficient. I'd like to know if there's an easy way to do it similar to `unfold`.

Comment: You could also prove `forall n l, all_zero (n :: l) = andb (beq_nat n 0) (all_zero l)` and rewrite with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that `simpl` will do what you want. If you have a more complicated goal, with functions that you want to apply and functions that you want to keep as they are, you might need to use the various options of the `cbv` tactic (see http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic127).

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
unfold all_zero; fold all_zero.
```

At least here for me that yields:

```
true = (beq_nat n 0 && all_zero l)%bool
```

Comment: `unfold` followed by `fold` indeed works for `all_zero`, but not for polymorphic recursive functions. Here's one example: `Fixpoint none {X:Type} (t:X->bool) (l:list X) : bool := match l with | nil => true | h :: l' => andb (negb (t h)) (none t l') end.` `unfold none` followed by `fold none` results in the following error message: `Error: Cannot infer the implicit parameter X of none.` So I think a generic solution for unfolding a recursive function once will have to avoid using `unfold` in the first place, unless there is some way to supply parametric information to `fold`.

Comment: You can make the implicit Parameter `X` of `none` explicit by writing `@none`. If you write `fold @none.`, then Coq is able to give the argument explictly and searches for a suitable `X` in the current context, just as it does for the other all-quantified variables `t` and `l`. If there is ambiguity you can also specify the corresponding variables explicitly, i.e. `fold (@none X)`.